# Invoking perl code from my VM's Ubuntu machine through a java program in Windows

Tags: java, perl, zip

I wrote a perl script in my VM's ubuntu box, which streams a set of mp4 files and trying to invoke this script from windows through a java program. But I am not receiving the streamed files on my java side.

### My perl code looks like:

```
use Archive::Zip::SimpleZip qw($SimpleZipError);
my $z = new Archive::Zip::SimpleZip '-', Stream=>1
or die "Cannot create zip file: $SimpleZipError\n" ;

$z->add("Users/abc/abc/abc.mp4");                                          
$z->add("Users/abc/abc/abc1.mp4");
$z->close();

stream();
```

### Through my java program which is in Windows OS trying to invoke perl:

```
URL url = new URL("http://<ubuntu machine ipaddress>:port>/abc/abc.pl");
String urlStr = url.toString();

HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConn.setUseCaches(true);
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
return is;
```

From the above inputstream I am trying to export the content into a zip file but after my export zip file is downloading as a empty file.

Can some body help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities for why your scripts aren't working.

1. Your perl script doesn't work.
    There are issues if that is the entirety of your script.    There is no built in perl `stream()` and you haven't imported it from anywhere.  Does your perl script work if you run it from the command line?
2. The server with the perl script isn't configured to execute it as a cgi script.
   From the ubuntu box,  run `curl "http://localhost:port/abc/abc.pl"`  Do you get a stream of zip data or an error or nothing?  If you don't get a zip stream,  you'll need to configure your http server to serve cgi scripts.
3. Your server isn't accepting connections.
   From the windows box,  just go to your address in your browser.    If you get a zip file,  then it's working correctly.
4. Your java code is wrong.
   I don't have enough experience in java to know what could be changed.   It looks right as far as I can tell, but someone may need to correct that.

Comment: Thanks for you response Trenton.  (1) 'stream()' is streaming the content, so no issues with it. (2) When I hit curl "http://localhost:port>/abc/abc.pl" it's showing my perl code in the browser instead of streaming zip data or an error. (3) Didn't get this point.